# Error while using deep copy in python, Jepp

Tags: java, python, jepp

```
num = 6
SG=np.empty((num),dtype=object)
SG=[0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006]
SG1=np.empty((num),dtype=object)
for tempv in range(0,6):
    for tempt in range(tempv+1,6):
        if SG[tempv]==SG[tempt]:
            SG[tempt]=SG[tempt]+0.000001
SG1=deepcopy(SG)
```

While executing this code. This exception is thrown

```
jep.JepException: jep.JepException: <class 'copy.Error'>: un(deep)copyable object of type <class 'jep.PyJNumber'>
```

Comment: damn, works fine from standard python.

Comment: Not for me @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: The example you provide here does not use any features of jep so it works without errors for me in both a jep interpreter and a standard python interpreter. You need to provide a code example that is using jep so we can understand your problem.